# Copying a file from one Workbook to another but formulas point to first workbook

Tags: excel

I am copying worksheets from a workbook containing a bunch of templates, named TestLibrary, to a workbook where there is data to read in on another worksheet, this workbook is named SchedulingTest. There are formulas designed to point to a sheet named "Data" in SchedulingTest but when I copy them they try to point to a non existent sheet in TestLibrary named "Data".

For Example, one formula in TestLibrary reads "=Data!D2"
When it is copied to SchedulingTest it changes the formula to "=[TestLibrary.xlsx]Data!D2"

Preferably I would like a way to preserve the original formula so it will work in the new file. If this is not possible is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Do a find/replace of the `[TestLibrary.xlsx]`. Are you actually doing the copy with VBA, or why is this tagged VBA?

Comment: I am doing the copy with VBA. Is there a way to do Find/Replace automatically within the same VBA Code?

Comment: Sure. If you need a head-start, use the macro recorder and do the find/replace manually.